# ORA-12528 and ORA-12505 error on Oracle database 11g

Tags: oracle, instance, listener

It's been one week since I last tried to run my final project that I worked on in my last internship at some banking company.

Suddenly, my webapps (Java project) in Eclipse can't start. In the log it says that it failed to make a connection to the Oracle database, with some error listener in it. So I try to connect the database manually from the SQL developer. It says

> ORA-12528: TNS:Listener: All Appropriate instances are blocking new connections.

I've read some solutions, and I tried to restart the Oracle services including the orcl and listener. After I restarted it, the error becomes

> ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

After a while, it becomes ORA-12528 again. Can someone help? My thesis defense is next week.

alert_ORCL.txt log (SID=ORCL):

```
***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12641, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 05-MAR-2015 21:28:24
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12641

TNS-12641: Authentication service failed to initialize
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (4204) as a result of ORA-609
Thu Mar 05 21:28:26 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12641, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 05-MAR-2015 21:28:26
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12641

TNS-12641: Authentication service failed to initialize
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (7280) as a result of ORA-609
Thu Mar 05 21:28:28 2015
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. !
Thu Mar 05 21:28:40 2015
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. !
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: Message 4500 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=SOSD
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. !
Thu Mar 05 21:28:49 2015
Errors in file c:\app\nico\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_psp0_3752.trc:
ORA-09314: sltln: error translating logical name
OSD-04503: Message 4503 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=SOSD
PSP0 (ospid: 3752): terminating the instance due to error 9314
Fri Mar 06 09:33:19 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Fri Mar 06 09:33:21 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=2532 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:21 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=3568 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=3572 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=3212 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=3856 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=3332 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=3828 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=3648 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=3840 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=2176 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=3688 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=2612 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=3004 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=1180 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
alter database mount exclusive
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=2088 
                                                                                                                                                     Fri Mar 06 09:39:14 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Fri Mar 06 09:39:39 2015
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Fri Mar 06 09:40:08 2015
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Fri Mar 06 09:40:17 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=6128 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:18 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=6132 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=6136 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=6140 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=4212 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=3460 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=2884 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=4644 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=2744 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=5160 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=5156 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=5228 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=5252 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=5240 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=5244 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:34 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Fri Mar 06 09:40:40 2015
Checker run found 1 new persistent data failures
Fri Mar 06 11:19:13 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 06-MAR-2015 11:19:13
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Fri Mar 06 12:17:21 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Fri Mar 06 12:17:26 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=3276 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:26 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=368 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=4952 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=900 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=888 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=868 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=884 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=880 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=876 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=832 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=776 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=4956 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=5008 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=4860 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=2032 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Fri Mar 06 14:09:50 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 06-MAR-2015 14:09:50
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Mar 09 14:25:48 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 14:25:53 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=3612 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:53 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=3616 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=3620 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=3628 
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=3632 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=3636 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=3644 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=3648 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=3652 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=3656 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=3660 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=3664 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=3668 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=3672 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=3676 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 14:25:56 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:00:16 2015
Shutting down instance (immediate)
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 1
All dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
alter database close normal
ORA-1507 signalled during: alter database close normal...
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=6964 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=8328 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=2460 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=7756 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=2280 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=7040 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=8340 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=7728 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=796 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=5292 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=7896 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=4812 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=6792 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=8808 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6436 
Mon Mar 09 16:12:11 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Mon Mar 09 16:12:26 2015
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
Mon Mar 09 16:12:37 2015
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Mon Mar 09 16:13:04 2015
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 16:13:09 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=5916 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=5920 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=5924 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=6004 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=6008 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=6016 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=6028 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=6032 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=6052 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=6056 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=6060 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=6064 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=6068 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=6072 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6076 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:18 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:23:23 2015
Shutting down instance (immediate)
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 1
All dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
alter database close normal
ORA-1507 signalled during: alter database close normal...
Mon Mar 09 16:24:43 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=6308 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=8020 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=7444 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=5936 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=8088 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=5216 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=5280 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=8160 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=5940 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=6020 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=4260 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=7496 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=1500 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=6960 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
alter database mount exclusive
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6624 
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:33:24 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 09-MAR-2015 16:33:24
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Mar 09 16:39:39 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
```

Comment: The alert log is on the filesystem http://csl-oracle.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/finding-location-of-oracle-alert-log.html?m=1

Comment: @Phil anything from the alert log? :( i'm kinda panicked

Comment: Did the IP address of the server change? If you use IP address in the listener.ora or tnsnames.ora file and the IP address changes that could be an issue. You should check both files and make sure that the IP address is correct for both. Also see if a listener is running, if you bring up a listener that is pointing to the wrong tns_admin directory then try to start it again the listener won't start if the port is blocked. Finally since you are using Windows you may want to reboot.

Comment: both is still the same:
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

the listener is up, but can't connect to the instance db...

Comment: try changing it from localhost to the name of your computer then stop and restart the listener service.

Comment: the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora? it says : "please check if it is opened in another program" .. can't save it.. My computer name is Nico-PC..

Comment: You probably need to run notepad with administrative privileges in order to save the files to the right places. You might also shutdown the listener service first.

Comment: it becomes:: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

Comment: this happens, everytime i restart the listener, it becomes ORA-12505..but eventually it will become ORA-12528 again..I've change localhost to -> Nico-PC but still, can't up..

Comment: try posting your listener.ora, tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files. There is likely a mistake somewhere, but its hard to know where without seeing the files. you can also try running netmgr to see if it can parse the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's signalling a 'ORA-214' during instance startup, which is really bad.

```
$ oerr ORA 214
00214, 00000, "control file '%s' version %s inconsistent with file '%s' version %s"
// *Cause: An inconsistent set of control files, datafiles/logfiles, and redo
//         files was used.
// *Action: Use a consistant set of control files, datafiles/logfiles, and redo
//         log files. That is, all the files must be for the same database
//         and from the same time period.
```

In other words, one of your control files might be corrupted. They are supposed to be identical.

To fix this, we'll try each control file in turn to see if the database starts OK with it.

Follow this step-by-step, to the letter. **MAKE SURE YOU BACK THEM UP, AS BELOW**. You have been warned.

Make a backup of BOTH control files to a location of your choice.
EG:

```
copy C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL C:\TMP\CONTROL01.CTL
copy C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL C:\TMP\CONTROL02.CTL
```

Next, make sure the database isn't up:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Mar 10 19:14:49 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> shutdown abort;
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL>
```

Now we'll overwrite the first control file with the second one, then attempt to start the database:

```
copy C:\TMP\CONTROL02.CTL C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL
```

Now try and start the database:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Mar 10 19:15:54 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  822579200 bytes
Fixed Size                  2257720 bytes
Variable Size             255855816 bytes
Database Buffers          557842432 bytes
Redo Buffers                6623232 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL>
```

If it says `Database opened` and doesn't throw a `ORA-` error, it's fixed.

If it throws another `ORA-214` or a message about a bad control file, we need to try the other control file. To do that, make sure the database is down (as above), then copy the other control file and try the startup again:

```
copy C:\TMP\CONTROL01.CTL C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL
copy C:\TMP\CONTROL01.CTL C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL
```

Note that this would have been easier to fix with 3 control files, as you could have md5'ed each one to find out which was the bad apple.

If the above doesn't work, you have further problems - if so, edit your question with the error message presented by SQL*Plus, and from the end of the alert log.

**I cannot reinforce how important it is that you backup the two control files somewhere safe before trying the above!**

It's entirely possible that there's another problem with a data file or redo log file, but we'll try this first.

Comment: THANKS PHIL! THIS SOLUTION SAVED MY DAY! LOOKING FORWARD TO LEARN MORE FROM YOU! :)